# Flutter Lower drop-down error when selecting drop-down

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdownbutton

I made the code like this.

**model**

```
//higt Code
class WorkPlaceAddBusinessAcode{
  late String? aCode;
  late String? aName;
        
  WorkPlaceAddBusinessAcode(Map mapJson) {
    this.aCode = mapJson['aCode'];
    this.aName = mapJson['aName'];
  }
}
        
//low Code
class WorkPlaceAddBusinessDcode{
  late String? aCode;
  late String? dCode;
  late String? dName;
        
  WorkPlaceAddBusinessDcode(Map mapJson) {
    this.aCode = mapJson['aCode'];
    this.dCode = mapJson['dCode'];
    this.dName = mapJson['dName'];
  }
}
```

**High DropItem Data map**

```
Map<String, String> bsACode() {
  String jsonData =
    '{"items" : [{"aCode" : "A", "aName" : "a1"},{"aCode" : "B", "aName" : "b1"},{"aCode" : "C", "aName" : "c1"},{"aCode" : "D", "aName" : "d1"}]}';
    
  dynamic jsonItem = json.decode(jsonData);
  List fData = jsonItem['items'];
  List flData = List.generate(
    0,
    (index) => index,
  );
    
  fData.forEach((element) {
    flData.add(WorkPlaceAddBusinessAcode(element));
  });
    
  Map<String, String>? bsAdata = {};
  for (int i = 0; i < flData.length; i++) {
    bsAdata[flData[i].aCode] = flData[i].aName;
  }
    
  return bsAdata;
}
```

**Low DropItem Data Map**

```
Map<String, String> bsDCode(String aCode){
    
  String jsonData =
    '{"items" : [{"aCode" : "X", "dCode" : "0000", "dName" : "Please select"}, {"aCode" : "A", "dCode" : "0110", "dName" : "aa"}, {"aCode" : "A", "dCode" : "0110", "dName" : "bb"}, {"aCode" : "B", "dCode" : "0110", "dName" : "cc"}, {"aCode" : "B", "dCode" : "0110", "dName" : "dd"}]}';
    
  dynamic jsonItem = json.decode(jsonData);
  List fData  = jsonItem['items'];
  List flData = List.generate(
    0,
    (index) => index
  );
    
  fData.forEach((element) {
    flData.add(WorkPlaceAddBusinessDcode(element));
  });
    
  Map<String, String>? bsDdata = {};
  for(int i = 0; i < flData.length; i++)
  {
    if( flData[i].aCode == aCode || flData[i].aCode == "X" )
    {
      bsDdata[flData[i].dCode + "-$i"] = flData[i].dName;
    }
  }
    
  return bsDdata;
}
```

**Code**

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}
    
class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
    
  FocusNode? _focusNode;
    
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
  }
    
  @override
  void dispose(){
    _focusNode!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
    
  late String bsDitem = "";
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: newAppBar(),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
              Config.dsize!.width * 0.025,
              Config.dsize!.height * 0.01,
              Config.dsize!.width * 0.025,
              Config.dsize!.height * 0.01),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                    isExpanded : true,
                    onChanged: (String? newVal) {
                      setState(() {
                        bsDitem = newVal!;
                      });
                    },
                    hint: Text("선택하세요"),
                    focusNode: _focusNode,
                    items: bsACode()
                      .entries
                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                        (MapEntry<String, String> e) =>
                          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: e.key,
                            child: Text(e.value),
                         )).toList(),
                 ),
               ),
    
               //next dropDownButton
               SizedBox(
                 child: test(bsDitem),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }


  ...low dropDownButton create...
}

newAppBar() {
  return AppBar(
    title: Text("ddd"),
  );
}
```

**low dropDownButton create**

```
Widget? test(String item){
  Widget? wItem;

  if( item == "")
  {
    wItem = DropdownButtonFormField(
      isExpanded: true,
      hint:   Text("업종을 선택해 주세요"),
      onChanged: null,
      items: [],
      onTap: (){FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);},
    );
  }
  else
  {
    wItem = DropdownButtonFormField(
      isExpanded: true,
      hint: Text("선택하세요"),
      onChanged: (String? newVal) {
      },
      items: bsDCode(item).entries.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
        (MapEntry<String, String> e) =>
          DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: e.value,
            child: Text(e.value),
     )).toList(),
   );
    
  }
    
  return wItem;
}
```

*But when you change the top button, there is a bug.*

> There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: aa.
> Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
> 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 915 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
> items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) {
> return item.value == value;
> }).length == 1'

Is there a way to solve it?
I desperately need help. Please help me.

Comment: the error message is telling either your dropdown values isn't unique or the `value` of dropdownButton doesn't contain on any dropdownMenuItem value

Comment: Even if you make a value and put it in, it comes out the same.